# Safely transferring specific content from a raspberry pi to my mac

Tags: data-transfer

I am new to Pi and I have a noob question. I want to transfer the videos and images I have captured with raspberry pi to my computer. What is the safest way to transfer just the images from the SD card of the raspberry pi?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello and welcome! What do you mean by "safest"?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities. You can install support for `ext4` on OSX and plug in the SD Card. A better solution would be to install `netatalk` on the Pi which will allow you to connect from your Mac using Finder over your LAN. Search this site for `netatalk` for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would call power cycling the rpi the second least data-integraty-safe thing you could do to it (high load beeing the worst). nice-ed [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)/ssh would be the safest for data-integraty and  transmission-privacy. Both OS X and raspbian support disk encription, and [backup software](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) if you want them

```
nice rsync --bwlimit=5000 --exclude '*thumbs*' -a -v -u pi@192.168.0.1234:~/img ~/Documents/rpi_img
```